# Error deserializing .bin file

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, bin

As the title suggests I'm having trouble deserializing a .bin file. I keep receiving the following error.

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The input stream is not a valid binary format.
>   The starting contents (in bytes) are:
>   15-8C-BF-02-1B-0C-5C-02-15-02-15-02-18-0D-63-6F-6E ...

I can't understand what is causing this to happen

Code:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open("client_master.bin", FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])bf.Deserialize(fs);

            TMemoryBuffer trans = new TMemoryBuffer(bytes);
            TCompactProtocol tbProto = new TCompactProtocol(trans);
            MasterData data = new MasterData();
            data.Read(tbProto);


            return data;
        }
```

Comment: OK, wheres the code used to write the file?  it could be its been written oddly too.

Comment: Are you serializing byte[] or a real type?

Comment: This is one of the issues, as I'm downloading the bin from a server I'm unsure what code was used to write the file.